# Adjust height of an element to another element with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, navigation, slider, resize, orientation

I am using a slider with left and right arrows for navigation at the top of the image. The div of the arrows should have the same height as the image.

I got this working on page load and also on resizing the screen, but after changing the orientation the height is not adjusted immediately. It only changes either after some seconds or after some seconds when an interaction has occurred.

Is there any trick how I can make this happen immediately after changing the orientation?

This is my JavaScript-Code:

```
<script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
              var divHeight = $(".divImage")
                .height();
                $('.divNavigation').height(divHeight);
});
      $(window).resize(function() {
              var divHeight = $(".divImage")
                .height();
                $('.divNavigation').height(divHeight);
});
      $(window).on('resize orientationchange', function() {
              var divHeight = $(".divImage")
                .height();
                $('.divNavigation').height(divHeight);
});
</script>
```

I added three conditions to my JS code. 1. run immediately on page load, 2. run when the screen is resized, 3. run when the orientation is changed. I expected all three to work properly.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Today I tried a few more codes to solve this issue, but it didn't help. Does anyone have an idea how to get the resize on orientation change working immediately?